# Hive's Bucketing Duplicates on Insert

Tags: hive

I have a Hive table that is partitioned on year and month and bucketed by day. Here's the DDL (initially empty):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db.myTable (
  id STRING,
  ...,
  date INT
) 
PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT)
CLUSTERED BY (date) INTO 31 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '<myTable-hdfs-path>';
```

When inserting to the Hive table, from documentation, it should have only at most 31 HDFS files (called buckets). I tried doing single-row inserts on this table (the last field is the date/day field).

```
INSERT INTO db.myTable
PARTITION (year=2015, month=10)
VALUES ('1447372800', ... , 15);
```

The MapReduce job creates 31 files in `<myTable-hdfs-path>/year=2015/month=10`, with only one file (say `00000_0`) having non-zero bytes size while the rest are 0.

When I attempt to insert another entry with same year, month, date (the other values are different), the MapReduce job creates another set of 31 files (total of 62) similar to the first insert.

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the second insert should simply append the entry to 00000_0, respecting the table's clustering. Why is this behaving 'weirdly'?

P.S. I'm using Hive v1.1.0 on Cloudera CDH QuickStart 5.4.0

Comment: That's the way Hive works. Each *INSERT* produces a set of **immutable** HDFS files. That's why the recent "transaction support" requires periodic compaction of these files -- among other things. In other words, if you want MySQL, then use MySQL.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Small inserts then will waste HDFS space as every small file created occupies one HDFS block, which is significantly bigger than the inserted data. Is that correct? Does this then makes bucketing more efficient on bulk loading rather than multiple small inserts?

Comment: **1.** HDFS "block size" has nothing to do with a physical disk block/segment/whatever. It is just an **indication** that when a single file gets bigger that "block size", it should be split automatically into 2+ **logical blocks**. Different blocks are replicated on different machines and can be read in parallel. //// Bottom line : having many small/emply files has very little impact on actual HDFS disk usage; but it may have an impact on the RAM usage of the NameNodes (which store the whole filesystem tree in memory).

Comment: **2.** Hive has been designed for read-only access to large sets of large files. Later it has been retrofitted for large writes. Recently it has been adapted for streaming *INSERTs* and, possibly, atomic *INSERTs* inside of transactions (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions) but there are a lot of prerequisites and it's like using a bulldozer to go shopping downtown //// Bottom line: if you want atomic transactions, use a real database! Even Hive uses a RDBMS for its MetaStore, there's a good reason!